# Derivative of $\tan^{-1}x$ with tangents.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, derivatives, trigonometry

Show that the tangent to the curve $y=\tan^{-1}(x)$ at the point where $x=-1$ is perpendicular to the normal to the curve at the point where $x=1$. Find the $x$-coordinate of the point where this tangent and normal intersect.

I used the rule of tan to find the gradient of the tangent as $1/2$ and the normal as $-2$. But I got the equation of the tangent as $y=1/2x - 0.28$ and the normal as $y=-2x + 2.78$. I think these are wrong. In the end I got $x=1$ while the correct answer is $(3+\pi)/5$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the correct equations, but the wrong final $x$ intersection. If you solve the system of $y=\dfrac{1}{2} x -0.28$ and $y=-2x+2.78$ you find $x=1.22$ which is approximately equal to $\dfrac{3+\pi}{5}$.

No need for approximations. Better keep the equations $y=\dfrac{1}{2} x + \dfrac{1}{2} - \dfrac{\pi}{4}$ and $y=-2x+2 + \dfrac{\pi}{4}$ to have the exact answer, it will be an easy system to solve.

Comment: by the time to form my answer, it became already answered :)

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to MSE! (I'm new too :D ) Your equations of the lines are correct, but the points you found are rounded to two decimal places and not exact answers. We know from the unit circle that $\arctan(1)=\frac{\pi}{4}$ and $\arctan(-1)=-\frac{\pi}{4}$ -- we don't need a calculator to figure that out. Therefore, the equations of the lines should be $y=-2x+2+\frac{\pi}{4}$ (normal) and $y=\frac{1}{2}x+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{\pi}{4}$ (tangent). If you set these equal and solve for $x$, you will get the correct answer, $x=\frac{3+\pi}{5}$.

Comment: Incidentally, $\frac{3+\pi}{5} \approx 1.23$, which is pretty close to $1$. So again, you were close, but it seems the problem was asking for an exact answer.